# Share files in two folders

Tags: svn

I have a file named Branding.ini in the following folders. The content of the file is same in the two folders. Is it possible to refer a copy of the same in the two folders, So that if one file is modified, the same is reflected in the other folder?

svn/ICEConnect200/trunk/Source/Application Files/Bin/Licensing/32 Bit/ASWorx
svn/ICEConnect200/trunk/Source/Application Files/Bin/Licensing/64 Bit/ASWorx

What is the best mechanism to address the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the version of Subversion you are using on the server (and client). So these are the 2 answers:

- Up to version 1.5.x (included), this is not possible. Subversion provided up from version (I think) 1.4.x the possibility to share whole folders, but not single file. The feature is named `svn:external`, you will find documentation [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html).
- Since version 1.6.x, it is possible to share single files. It is a variation to the previous `svn:external` and documented [here](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.advanced.externals.html). Search for the part that begins with `Subversion 1.6 brings another improvement to externals definitions by introducing external definitions for files.`

So you can then store your files you want to share in some part of the repository, and link to that file from another part then. You should decide if you want to use one of the 2 locations you have as the source, and the other as the target.

If you have the file external from the head, you are even allowed to change any location, and commit it. After that (and an update), your new version is visible at all locations you reference it.